# Best approach for adding SignalR (ASP.NET CORE 6 MVC backend) to a Vue2 app (cdn version for frontend)

Tags: vuejs2, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

I am looking to add SignalR to an app I have been building that uses the CDN version of vue2. My vue components makes API calls via axios to my controllers which either pull data from our database or push data to our database. I do not currently have any state management because its not as easy to do via the cdn version of vue and I am planning to eventually move to Vue 3 and Pinia but I would like to get SignalR off the ground first and test it out via the current state of my app.

How would I implement this as most of the resources I see use state management and not the cdn version of vue.

Where would i implement the following? Inside my components or in my main.js?

```
                var signalR = window.signalR;
            try {
                this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(window.location.origin + '/dashboardHub', {})
                    .withAutomaticReconnect()
                    .build();
                console.log('Signalr Connection', connection);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('SignalR error ', error)
            }
```